# Anyone have a workaround for the aspnet menu control not rendering properly in ie8?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, aspmenu

I am programming asp.net in C# using vs2008.

My app runs fine in ie7, but the drop down menu does not render in ie8. A white rectangle shows up instead of the menu items. I checked viewsource and the html for the menu looks good.

Anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">` meta-tag as detailed here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/developers-new.aspx#dom

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/giorgio/archive/2009/02/01/asp-net-menu-and-ie8-rendering-white-issue.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ms released the patch, it is bug in their dropdown control